# MySQL can't get contents of cell

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I just dont understand:

I want to get the name of the image from MySQL table like so:

```
$q = "SELECT legend FROM ps_image_lang WHERE id_image=27";      
$res = mysqli_query($con, $q);  
print_r($res);
```

But in the browser window i get such output:

> mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 3 [type] => 0 )

Why do i get such output and how should i do it properly ?

Comment: `$res` is a mysqli object. You need to do a fetch, ie. [`print_r(mysqli_fetch_assoc($res));`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to fetch your result, here you go:

```
$q = "SELECT legend FROM ps_image_lang WHERE id_image=27";      
$res = mysqli_query($con, $q); 

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

print_r($row);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just only use $res. It will return resource. You must process the resource.

```
$q = "SELECT legend FROM ps_image_lang WHERE id_image=27";      
$res = mysqli_query($con, $q); 
if(!$res){
    $row=mysql_fetch_row($rest);
    print_r($row);
} else
    echo "No row is fetched";
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, sorry, forgot to transform it to an array. Soooooooooo the solution is:

```
function res_to_array($res) {

    //$con = con();

    $count = 0;
    $res_array = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $res_array[$count] = $row;
        $count++;
    }

    return $res_array;
}

$q = "SELECT legend FROM ps_image_lang WHERE id_image=27";  
$res = mysqli_query($con, $q);  
$res = res_to_array($res);  
print_r($res);
```

And now i get the contents. Sorry again for asking reaaaly basic questions. :) Or... Like Tomasz Turkowski said: just mysqli_fetch_assoc(); Again, sorry sorry soryy.